# Known Variant of Set Cover?

Tags: set-cover

Consider the following variant of set cover:

Given: Target set $T$ and a collection of sets $\mathcal{C}$, such that $T \subseteq \bigcup_{C \in \mathcal{C}} C$.

Wanted: A subset $\mathcal{C'}$ of $\mathcal{C}$, such that $T \subseteq \bigcup_{C \in \cal{C'}} C$ and $|\bigcup_{C \in \cal{C'}} C|$ is minimal.

In other words, we are looking for a covering of $T$ that covers as few additional elements as possible.

It is relatively easy to see that this problem is NP-complete.

Is this a known problem? What is its name?

Comment: One of the standard generalizations of Set Cover is _minimizing a linear function subject to a submodular constraint_.  See e.g. https://algnotes.info/on/background/set-cover-wolsey/ .  Doesn't look like it quite captures your problem though.

Comment: Ouch, indeed the $\sum$'s should be $\bigcup$'s.

Answer (score 3):

We can abstract this problem as submodular minimization (minimize additional covers) under submodular cover (set cover) constraint. I'll point you towards two papers in this area.

- Iwata and Nagano, 2009. Submodular function minimization under covering constraints. https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/5438589
- Kamiyama, 2011. Submodular function minimization under a submodular set covering constraint. https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-20877-5_14

The first paper proves that a primal-dual algorithm achieves constant approximation if maximum frequency is fixed. The second paper gives a more careful bound.

Comment: The Iwata and Nagano paper proves a strong lower bound on the approximation when the maximum frequency is not bounded. The lower bound should probably hold for the OPs problem as well.